# Where is setLocalStorage documented?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

1) Where can I find the JavaScript function documentation for setLocalStorage()?
On DuckDuckGo I get 0 results. Is it a deprecated function and therefore not anymore documented?

And then I have a follow-up question:
2) How is setLocalStorage different from localStorage.setItem()?

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: I think it's different, as setLocalStorage doesn't exist, are you getting this from some lib?

Comment: @Keith I'm quite sure setLocalStorage does indeed not exist. It's probably just a wrapper for localStorage.setItem().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a JS function, definitely not a standard one. It doesn't exist in Chrome, and there appears to be no MDN documentation for it either; this is probably why you can't find any search results.

The only way to access local storage is via the global (window) localStorage object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Maybe this function is custom code in some library or framework you are working with?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was working with someone else's code and I just didn't see the definition among the results. It was indeed a wrapper function.
`setLocalStorage = (key, value) => { localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value)); }`